# Would like to add generic code, like #define

Tags: php

I would like to add translation to my site to all sorts of languages. 
I thought of defining chunks of code in different language files,
Is that possible to create seperate files for translation in something like this manner ? :

the generic file:

```
// index.php
// say $_SESSION['lang'] = rtlLANG;
<?php include($_SESSION['lang'].".php");?>
<html>
 <body>
  <?php MAIN_WELCOME_MESSAGE; ?>
 </body>
</html>

// some rtlLANG.php
define("MAIN_WELCOME_MESSAGE","
 echo '<table style="direction:ltr;">';
 echo 'welcome rtl language readers';
");


// some ltrLANG.php
define("MAIN_WELCOME_MESSAGE","
 echo '<table style="direction:rtl;">';
 echo 'welcome rtl language readers';
");
```

is it possible to somehow define these chunks of code ? (I know that not as it is at least)
How can I implement different ways to layout my content for each language otherwise ?

Comment: The above would work but probably isn't the best way to do so, just change the definition to something like `define('MAIN_WELCOME_MESSAGE','<table style="direction:rtl;">welcome rtl language readers'); echo MAIN_WELCOME_MESSAGE;` Otherwise the answer by ceejayoz is suitable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard (cross language, too) library gettext. http://php.net/gettext

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways for implementing multilang support. here's my suggestion:

from my experience with html/css it's best to create 2 versions of the design - rtl and ltr. if you use MVC you could set a dir for the views (or templates).

you should have a list of languages, and for each you need to say whether it's ltr or rtl.

now for the actual translation: in your views/templates or html code/error and notice messages you can load the actual text. you can either write your own code, or (i'd recommend) use gettext (http://www.gnu.org/s/gettext/)